# Process raw interval value in sqlalchemy TypeDecorator

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have an Interval column, and I want to make it works with `dateutil.relativedelta` object by imlementing new type based on Interval with processing value. How can I do it?

```py
class RelativeInterval(TypeDecorator):

    impl = Interval

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect) -> Any:
        print(value, type(value))
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value: Any, dialect):
        print(value, type(value))
        return value
```

In the following methods value is already `datetime.timedelta` value, but I want to use such delta values like `month` or `year`, which are not supported in `datetime.timedelta` class. So I want to write methods to automatically process raw interval value to `dateutil.relativedelta` when I get value and process string like '1 month' or `datetime.timedelta` or `dateutil.relativedelta` instance to postgresql native interval, when I set value.

I know, that I can do it on driver level [like this](https://groups.google.com/g/sqlalchemy/c/dtFAoZdxt7o/m/wRTZO54dCAAJ), but I want to not override all intervals. Just one column.

Comment: I've solved my problem by driver-level solution and by adding converter "relativedelta to string in Interval format". So, I'll use this solution, but my question is still actual, because my solution is not so good (override converting on database driver level may cause problems, I think).